# Delete all the local files and download a fresh copy from git

Tags: git

I understand it is possible to delete everything locally and just start fresh but I wonder if there is an easier way when you do not require to keep anything done locally using git commands.

for example if I added bunch of files locally that I would like to remove and just download the latest master copy.

> Please note: Reading the other questions (there are many; I read them before posting), git help & blog posts I wasn't sure if it's going to reset my repository or not which is why I posted this question; I imagine someone with
>   the same exact issue might want to validate and that's what I have done through comments. and that is why I don't think its a duplicate although it might have the same response.

Comment: Something like [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)?

Comment: Also `git clean -dfx && git pull origin master`

Comment: You can git rm to get rid of everything

Comment: I seen this; but didn't try it because I do not want to make any changes to my repo.

Comment: okay so I git rm and git pull origin master ? git rm is not going to delete my master copy in the cloud ?

Comment: okay too many options which one is doing the job !

Comment: Depends on what job you want to be done. That point is rather unclear to me currently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove the git commit which you have added locally do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

To remove the remove the uncommitted files, do:

```
git clean -fd
```

check out other git Clean options here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

and then do

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

or

```
   git pull
```

Comment: I did git reset --hard HEAD^ and my head went back to one before my last commit, is that what is suppose to happen ?

Comment: if You have committed your changes use the first command else use the second one..